# create table in LaTeX

Tags: tables

LaTeX newbie here. Please how do I create the table below?

I tried to do it but I've not been able to figure out how to fit the types of employment without a heading on top like 1999, 2004 and 2006 in the three other columns.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Just write the first row as ` & 1999 & 2004 & 2006 \\ `.

Comment: You can start [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't get very far. Like I said the issue is how to enter the types of employment without a column heading like 1999, 2004 and 2006.

Answer (score 4):

A MWE to create a table similar to the one shown in the question would be the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Types of Employment as Percentage of Sample Population}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule 
& \textit{1999} & \textit{2004} & \textit{2006} \\
\midrule
Family agriculture & 30.8 & 36.60 & 37.80 \\
Nonagriculture self-employed & 24.1 & 25.80 & 22.90 \\
Nonagriculture unpaid family work & 0 & 0.08 & 0.06 \\
Wage employment & 15.0 & 10.40 & 10.00 \\
Apprenticeship & 2.1 & 1.10 & 1.90 \\
Unemployed & 1.7 & 2.40 & 1.90 \\
Not in the labor force & 26.4 & 23.70 & 25.50 \\
\bottomrule
\footnotesize Source:
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to consider to align the numbers with respect to the decimal separator instead of a right-justified alignment. This can easily be achieved with the help of the `siunitx` package as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Types of Employment as Percentage of Sample Population}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*3S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule 
& \textit{1999} & \textit{2004} & \textit{2006} \\
\midrule
Family agriculture & 30.8 & 36.60 & 37.80 \\
Nonagriculture self-employed & 24.1 & 25.80 & 22.90 \\
Nonagriculture unpaid family work & 0 & 0.08 & 0.06 \\
Wage employment & 15.0 & 10.40 & 10.00 \\
Apprenticeship & 2.1 & 1.10 & 1.90 \\
Unemployed & 1.7 & 2.40 & 1.90 \\
Not in the labor force & 26.4 & 23.70 & 25.50 \\
\bottomrule
\footnotesize Source:
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]